# Why does stock / ETF data go FUBAR?

Tags: market-data, stock-split

I hold units in the [JNK](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/JNK/) junk bond ETF.  On April 1st, it underwent a three-to-one reverse split so that three units were converted to one unit after the reverse split.  That meant the unit price went from (approximately) $36 to $108 because one new unit is worth three of the old units.

On Saturday, I was reviewing my portfolio and noticed that the unit price shown by my broker for JNK had gone from $108 to $36. But the number of units I had were still the post-reverse-split number.

Searching the internet on Saturday showed the $36 price. Searching now shows the $108 price.

Did anyone else notice this?

Does this sort of data corruption happen with stock splits / reverse-splits?

On Monday, the data all reverted to the $108 value -- including any search responses.

The screenshot below shows the problem: The **Last Price** is $36.09 and yet the trading plot from the previous day's trades shows about $108.30 as the price.

[image: Price problem being shown.]

Comment: yes it happens often with splits, the data will sort itself out eventually

Comment: "'What we've got here is failure to communicate."  Some brokers and web sites fail to update corporate changes in a timely manner.  Yahoo and MarketWatch are still displaying FUBAR graphs.  A broker should not be as irresponsible.